# MX Canvas maximum size

Tags: apache-flex

Anyone here know the maximum size of a Flex canvas or UIComponent? I know the old MovieClip class was limited to 2800x2800px.

take care,
lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flex 3 the UIComponent (which all visual objects extend) has the following properties, which can be changed as you see fit:

maxHeight="10000"
maxWidth="10000"

By extension, this applies to Canvas too (tricky to find unless you already know to search for 10,000!)